# How to specify a log scale y axis with stripplot in R?

Tags: r, lattice

How can I use `stripplot` from the lattice package with a log y axis? With `plot`, I can use the argument `log` and specify which axes I want on a log-scale. Is there some way of doing this with stripplot without recourse to taking the log of the numeric data and then specifying the y axes points?

Example code using `singer` data:

```
stripplot(voice.part ~ height, data = singer, aspect = 1,
      jitter.data = TRUE, xlab = "Height (inches)")
```

NB. This data doesn't need to be on a log scale, I'm just using it as an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fine tuning of the axes in plots with the lattice package are handled by the `scales` argument (see the appropriate entry on the `?xyplot` page). This argument is essentially a list, and two of the list components can be `x` and `y`, which are also lists with components that control the appearance of the x- and y-axes, respectively.

For a log scale on the x axis, use

```
stripplot(voice.part ~ height, data = singer, aspect = 1,
      jitter.data = TRUE, xlab = "Height (inches)",
      scales = list(x = list(log = 2)))
```

Replace `2` with whatever log base you want.